# Laravel ajax send multi dimension associative array

Tags: ajax, laravel

I would like to do something very simple but I can't make it work, I only want to send via jquery ajax a multi dimensional array to laravel and get the data back.

For example:

```
var info = JSON.stringify([{'key':'val1'},{'key':'val2'},{'key':'val3'}]);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "{!! route('ajaxactivityperemployee') !!}",
data: {"mydata":info},
success: function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

On the other side, on my controller, I try this:

```
public function postActivityPerEmployee(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    return $input['mydata'][0]['key'];
}
```

I ve tried various combinations but I always end up with a 500 page error or in the console, I only get [ and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Don't stringify your `info` because you will send a string.

use this instead :

`var info = [{'key':'val1'},{'key':'val2'},{'key':'val3'}];`

which mean that you want to send an array of Objects

Comment: Ok, I ve tried it and now if I return $input['mydata'][0], I see in the console object object and if I try to return $input['mydata'][0]['key'], I get an error 500

Comment: you can check which error laravel returns to you, for example with chrome browser you can check with dev tools `F12` -> `Network`, you can see your request in red click on it and tell me about the error.

Comment: POST http://localhost/people/public/activityperemployee 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: When you click on your request you see on the right panel [Headers, Preview etc.] click on preview and send me the result. 
Example https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/imgs/network-headers.png

Comment: I gave up and went another way, I encoded every value as a single variable instead of passing an array and it is working fine now. I m sorry I couldn't make it work.